# referencia de um var dentro do for para global

Tags: python

então, eu queria saber com referencio as variáveis datas, listaComTudo, nomesDespesas e trasforma-las em globais para poder resolver um erro de "UnboundLocalError: local variable 'nomesDespesas' referenced before assignment"

```
    @app.route("/download", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
    def orac_detal():
                    global orac_detal                
                    state = {'gera':0, 'gera_total_csv':0, 'gera_orcamento':0, 'gera_total':0, 'taxas':0, 'gera_agrupamento':0, 'orac_detal':1}
                    m = np.zeros((156,96))



                    for loja in lojas:
                      if os.path.isfile("./.pickles/orcamentoAux_"+str(loja)+".pickle"):
                        with open(r"./.pickles/orcamentoAux_"+str(loja)+".pickle", "rb") as input_file:
                            foo = pickle.load(input_file)
                            datas = foo['datas'] # lista com todas as datas, para ser o cabeçalho da planilha
                            listaComTudo = foo['listaComTudo'] # lista de lista, em que cada lista interna tem os dados de uma despesa
                            nomesDespesas = foo['nomesDespesas'] # lista com o nome de todas as despesas, para ser inserida no final usando a função de colocar na primeira coluna
                datas=datas, listaComTudo=listaComTudo, nomesDespesas=nomesDespesas

                   for i in range(len(listaComTudo)):
                      m[i] += listaComTudo[i]

                   for i in range(len(listaComTudo)):
                      nomesDespesas[i] = nomesDespesas[i].replace(","," ")
                      listaComTudo[i] = [nomesDespesas[i]] + listaComTudo[i]

                   dicionario = {}
                   for i in range(len(nomesDespesas)):
                      chave = nomesDespesas[i][23:]
                      dicionario[chave] = m[i]  

                  df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data=dicionario, orient='index', columns=datas)
                  df.to_csv('despesas_detal.csv ' )

def download_file_named_in_unicode():
    return excel.make_response_from_array('despesas_detal.csv', "xls",
                                          file_name=u"despesas_detal")
```

Comment: Ué, você já usou `global orac_detal` para fazer isso, qual foi a dificuldade? Aliás, nem isso fez sentido, visto que `orac_detal` é o nome da função.

Comment: Seria legal você arrumar a identação do código na postagem. Em Python isso não é um "detalhe", em que como ficar identado ficou - e o código acima fica com erro de sintaxe por conta da identação.